# Maven - why does running a build of multiple packages result in a different result?

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Let's say I have a project with 2 modules, and 3 pom.xml files (1 for Module A, 1 for Module B, 1 parent pom.xml)

I've added the following plugin that verifies the code coverage diff between my changeset and another branch, and fails if it's below a certain threshold https://github.com/SurpSG/diff-coverage-maven-plugin

If I make NO code changes:

`mvn clean verify` -> success

`mvn clean verify -T 1C -pl moduleA -am -U` -> success

`mvn clean verify -T 1C -pl moduleA, moduleB -am -U` -> success

So as expected, my builds are passing because I made no code change.

Now if I make a code change to moduleA without proper unit test code coverage, here are the results.

`mvn clean verify -T 1C -pl moduleA -am -U` -> fail for moduleB, skipping moduleA

`mvn clean verify -T 1C -pl moduleB -am -U` -> success

`mvn clean verify -T 1C -pl moduleA, moduleB -am -U` -> fail for moduleB, skipping moduleA

This last case is what is puzzling me, why would moduleB be failing? why is it not running for each module without side-effects?

The issue is that the failure message is really not helpful and pointing to the wrong service.

Comment: Can you create a Small public repository demonstrating this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are observing some weird behaviour because plugin's author didn't pay much attention to maven internals:

```
private val rootProjectDir: File
  get() = reactorProjects[0].basedir
```

```
private fun collectExecFiles(): Set<File> {
 return if (dataFileIncludes == null) {
   setOf(dataFile)
 } else {
   FileUtils.getFiles(rootProjectDir, dataFileIncludes, dataFileExcludes).toSet()
 }
}
```

Injecting `reactorProjects` makes sense for [`@aggregator` mojos](https://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html), because when we are dealing with multi-module project structures and have parent-child relations we need special handling of such cases (for example, there are two mojos in `jacoco-maven-plugin`: `report` and `report-aggregate`). In your case plugin's author is trying to kill two rabbits with single shot, that in your particular case leads to the following:

when you run maven like `-pl moduleA -am` then when maven executes verify phase of `Module B` reactor projects are `Module A, Module B`, plugin tries to pick up `exec` files from `Module A` directory and fails: `Module A` depends on `Module B` and there are no `exec` files in `Module A` directory.